# A Riddle From a Madman

Tags: riddle

Today I met a madman with astonishing magical powers. He told me he could help me locate anything in my realm if I solved his riddle.
So I asked him for the riddle and he said,"I am the little thing that goes forth alone, and comes back in a line with my brothers."

*I don't know the answer, but I can test any suggestions.
*The answer has nothing to do with the identity of the madman.
*The answer is a 1 word answer.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzle.SE! Take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to earn your first badge. Did you come up with this riddle yourself? If not, could you please say where you got it from?

Comment: Its from a MUD called Avalon Rpg.

Comment: @Aelyn: Care to comment on any of the answers given?

Comment: I tried testing the bottom 5 answers...but they didnt work....but they're really nice answers though...

Comment: so, basically, you're asking us to solve a riddle in your game because you're stuck? :)

Comment: I know you're just asking a riddle you found, but I don't think it's a good one to ask here. Where, as here, many answers could fit, the riddle is under-specified. A well-crafted riddle gives enough information to rule in the intended solution while ruling out everything else. Also, keep in mind that (at least here) riddles are not interactive challenges—potential solutions should be testable by referring to *the riddle*, not by needing you to check on Avalon RPG and then get back to us. If the riddle lacks enough specificity to make that determination, then it's probably *too broad*.

Answer (score 12):

Sounds like the answer might be

> an Ant, which travels, often individually, far from the nest to find food, and finds its way back by following the [trail of pheromones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trail_pheromone) left by themselves or other ants. They are often seen coming back to the nest in a line.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the answer is:

> A [data packet](http://www.cellbiol.com/bioinformatics_web_development/chapter-1-internet-networks-and-tcp-ip/data-transmission-on-the-internet/). According to the link, data is transmitted throughout the internet in the form of small packets. I may have understood it wrongly, but I think a client sends a single packet of data as a request to the server (little thing going forth alone), and a torrent of data packets is sent back in reply (coming back with brothers in a line). Assuming that the text before the riddle is also relevant, it also ties in with how the "madman" will be able to help you find anything in his realm.

Comment: I like this answer! Also, kind of interesting how there's more than one plausible answer to questions like these

Comment: @Grace Around here we say that such questions are "too broad" because they admit many answers that are not ruled out by the question - and a well formed puzzle or riddle should have a single clearly correct answer (even if said answer isn't obvious to begin with). This riddle doesn't have enough substance in it to rule in or rule out these answers.

Comment: That's interesting to know @Rubio

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like a

> pea or a bean. It falls into the ground alone as a seed, and then grows into a plant with pea pods — multiple peas in a line.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

> An echo?

Because:

> A single sound is emitted (goes forth alone) and then repeatedly returns (comes back in a line of its “brothers”/similar copies of the sound).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is someone who is

> Passionate about his goal. 
>
>  He begins his journey alone but when he becomes successful, he is joined by his so called 'brothers'.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s a

> Second hand on the clock - it starts off before any of the others but always returns to the minute and hour hands?

Comment: He told its a little thing, by your answer the hour hand would be little than the second hand of the clock.

Comment: @Nappa In my head, it's little because it's thin.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think I'm right :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming it as a lifeless thing, it is

> A drop of rain water,

Which

> Falls from the sky as an individual one, but once collected in a storage/container - it can be made for distribution by pipes and hence goes in a line along with its brothers.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of:

> A switcher engine

as its job is to:

> sort railcars in a siding by connecting to cars and pulling/shunting them between lines.

Answer (score 0):

It might be:

> A bee. Similar to the ant logic. Though bee's that fly out and collect nectar are female so it doesn't fit the brothers line very well.